# Reusing description components in Swagger UI / OpenAPI

Tags: yaml, components, swagger, openapi, ref

I have an openAPI doc in which many of the actions will have some common elements in their description fields.

Is there a way to save a block of text and combine it with another in the description field?

```yaml
openapi: 3.0.3

info:
  title: API Title
  version: v1

paths:
  /example/path1:
    description: |
      This part of the description is unique for path1  

      The rest of this stuff is the same as path2 and others.
      ...
      How do I combine this section and reference it?

  /example/path2:
    description: |
      This is different from the other paths and unique to path2  

      The rest of this stuff is the same as path2 and others.
      ...
      How do I combine this section and reference it?
```